# Splitting the pyspark array elements by newline character in the same dataframe cell

Tags: pyspark

I have a requirement where I need to show the elements of an array in new lines but in the same dataframe cell.

I am using the collect_list function on grouped data to have the data elements stored in a list. - ['a','b','c']

However there is a requirement to show the data as one item per line but All items in same dataframe cell.

I have explained the AS IS and TO BE requirements pictorically in below image link (Sorry right now, I am not allowed to copy paste images directly here.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbLgv.png

We can call it cell wraping functionality similar to excel, but does anybody know how to do it in pyspark?

Thanks

Comment: We do not have cell wrapping in pyspark

Comment: Ok thanks. Any suggestions on how to achieve similar result may be by using something else apart from collect_list() function?